# Test django sqlite3 database with pytest in CI

Tags: python, django, testing, pytest, pytest-django

I have an updater class which updates database tables (modifies, removes, adds).

I need to write a tests for this updater. These tests will be called in gitlab CI.

```
python3.9 project/manage.py makemigrations
python3.9 project/manage.py migrate
pytest -s -v --cov --cov-config .coveragerc -ra --tb=short {posargs:}
```

"Test" database does not contain required tables until migrations call. I feel like there is existing "pytest mechanism" which allow to create fake sqlite3 database instance with performed migrations, which I do not know :D.

Django database config:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        "TEST": {
            "MIRROR": "default"
        }
    },
}
```

I have already installed `pytest-django` and marked test with `pytest.mark.django_db`.

Is it appropriate way of testing?